# Cloud Front Video Streaming

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront

I have a confusion about amazon cloud front streaming option. I have not signed up for AWS as yet so I want to be sure what I want.

The scenario is that I select a video to be streamed to iPhone at 2 am. The video is 30 minutes long. If a person opens up the video link at 2 10 am. From where will he see the video? Will he be viewing the video form the start or will he be viewing the video from 10 am onwards?

My second question is that can the user seek forward or backwards when I am streaming the video from cloudfront?

Basically I want to stream pre recorded webinars and I want to give the illusion to the user that its a live event without allowing them to seek forward or backs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would probably have to run it as a live stream. Otherwise its will just be a standard video stream where you can seek to any position in playback.

You can find some more information on how to do that here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/LiveStreamingAdobeFMS4.5.html

Answer (score 1):

After creating S3 Buckets and uploading files on it. Create web disribution for your bucket.
And for playing the video. Create a html Page

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>Amazon CloudFront Streaming with JW Player 6</TITLE> 

<script type='text/javascript' src='http://content.jwplatform.com/libraries/yQ0SAHQS.js'></script>

</HEAD>

<BODY>

<h1>Cloud Front Video Streaming</h1>

<div id="myElement">Loading the player...</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
var playerInstance = jwplayer("myElement");
playerInstance.setup({
    file: "http://d49asxxxxxxxxxxxx.cloudfront.net/Make-a-world-of-difference.mp4",

    width: 640,
    height: 360,
    title: 'Basic Video Embed',
    description: 'A video with a basic title and description!',
    mediaid: '123456'
});
</script>
</BODY>

</HTML>
```

Note: http://d49asxxxxxxxxxxxx.cloudfront.net is the domain name of your cloud front.

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://content.jwplatform.com/libraries/yQ0SAHQS.js'></script>

This is the script for JW Player.that can be found on the 
www.jwplayer.com/ after signup. 
Choose your player 16:9 or 480*720
```

You will get a script library code.  http://content.jwplatform.com/libraries/yQ0SAHQS.js